# Laravel 6 - Change routing url

Tags: url, routes, laravel-6

Im fairly new to Laravel, running version 6 atm. I have made a working feature that any registered user can edit their profile.

My issue is that I dont like the url being shown to the user like:

```
localhost/profile/16/edit
```

16 = userid

Route file:

```
Route::put('/profile/edit/{profile}','ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

Is there a way to change my route so its only displayed like: profile/edit, if any user has entered? They can enter any other user id in the url but only the auth user info will be show and be possible to edit but it bugs me that the url has an id in it. Any fancy routing method to change that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own issue.

Edited my routes to this:

```
Route::get('/profile/edit', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
Route::put('/profile/edit', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');
```